# How to get baseURL inside Vuejs method using vue router?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a method where need to create a string which consists of
base URL `/get-it` and some random generated string?

```
methods:{
GenerateURL(){
...
}
}
```

How can be it achieved? How can I either get base URL or /get-it with vue router but without navigating to that /get-it page which is empty?
I just need to use it as a string inside the component.

Answer (score 14):

From the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#route-object-properties):

> - $route.path
>
>   - type: string
>
>     A string that equals the path of the current route, always resolved as an absolute path. e.g. "/foo/bar"

So in your case you could do something like this:

```
methods:{
  GenerateURL(){
    var fullUrl = window.location.origin + this.$route.path + "/get-it/yourRandomString"
  }
}
```

[Location Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/origin).

Answer (score 9):

Simple and easy way to get baseUrl in VueJs is

```
var baseUrl = window.location.origin
```

Comment: Doesn't work because it is assuming the path is `/`

Answer (score 2):

Given https://mywebsite.com/some/vue/route

```js
import router from "@/router";

console.log(window.location.origin) // https://mywebsite.com
console.log(router.currentRoute.value.fullPath) // /some/vue/route
```

Answer (score 0):

This is so simple

```
// app.js
Vue.prototype.$url= window.location.origin;

// in component
console.log(this.$url)

output: https://stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: Doesn't work because it is assuming the path is `/`